# Associations with simple_form an input field (not checkboxes, selects. or radios)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I was hoping someone could please help me with a simple_form association that I'm trying to do.
What I want to do is to create a simple_form for a music video that that has an association in the form of a has many through. My schema looks like this:

```
create_table "music_videos", force: true do |t|
t.string  "song_title",  null: false
t.string  "venue",       null: false
t.string  "location",    null: false
t.string  "description", null: false
t.string  "url_id",      null: false
t.integer "user_id",     null: false
end

create_table "music_videos_tags", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "music_video_id", null: false
  t.integer "tag_id",         null: false
end

add_index "music_videos_tags", ["music_video_id"], name:     
index_music_videos_tags_on_music_video_id", using: :btree
add_index "music_videos_tags", ["tag_id"], name: "index_music_videos_tags_on_tag_id",   
using: :btree

create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
  t.string "name", null: false
end
```

Music Videos has many tags through music_video_taggings vice versa. But I'm confused on how to do accomplish the association with simple_form. I have a new.html.erb with a form like so:

```
<h1>Submit Your Video</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @music_video url: music_videos_path, method: :post do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :song_title %>
 <%= f.input :venue %>
 <%= f.input :location, label: "City", collection: MusicVideo::CITY %>
 <%= f.input :description %>
 <%= f.input :url_id, label: "Paste url id ex. 82237472" %>
 <%= f.input :name, label: "Tag" %>
 <%= f.submit %>
```

Now I know, I'm supposed to put an association for f.input :name, but I don't want checkboxes, selects, or radios. How can I do this? I thought about creating a form for both @music_videos, and @tags right at the top of the form, but I don't think that will work though.The errors that I keep receiving are that there is an undefined method name. Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for awhile. Some help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `I don't want checkboxes, selects, or radios` then what do you want that field to be? Just a text field?

Comment: Exactly. I want it to just be a simple f.input, but the docs just cover associations through selects, checkboxes, and radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
 <%= f.input :name, label: "Tag" %>
```

With

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :tags do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :name, label: "Tag"  %>
  <% end %>
```

Refer to **[Nested Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)** in Simple Form for more details.

Comment: Thank God....it worked! If you were sitting next to me I'd give you a hug. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.